# Is there a way to convert a folder of ipynb files to a single pdf?

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, latex, pdflatex

I have a folder of ipynb files which I would like to have converted to a single pdf document. To convert each individual one, I am exporting in vscode using LaTex. However, I have a lot of related workbooks which I would like to have converted into one pdf.

If this isn't possible, is there at least a way to quickly print the whole folder into individual files?

Answer (score 2):

Given you have a Jupyter environment, you could use the `jupyter nbconvert` command. Here's an example notebook. It assumes you have `sudo` privileges.

```
!sudo apt-get -y install wkhtmltopdf
!pip install pdfkit
import os
import pdfkit

path = '/path/to/files'   # this will be fiddly to get right
files = os.listdir(path)

files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.ipynb')]

ss = ''
for f in files_txt:
    ss = ss + ' "' + f + '"'

cmd = 'jupyter nbconvert ' + ss + ' --to html --stdout > combined.html'
os.system(cmd)
pdfkit.from_url('./combined.html', 'combined.pdf')
```

It converts to `html` first into a single `html` file then converts to `pdf`. Using `nbconvert` to convert directly to `pdf` proved too much of a problem.